# Springboot Unable to access a resource inside a dependent jar's classpath

Tags: spring-boot, classpath, inputstream, classloader, property-files

I have a spring boot JAR MyMain.jar, which has dependent jars inside BOOT-INF/lib.

I am trying to access a property file inside the BOOT-INF/lib/MyDep.jar/abcd.properties.

I tried the below code.

```
InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("abcd.properties").getInputStream();
System.out.println("InputStream : "+in);
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));          
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This works perfect inside my Eclipse IDE. but when I run it on command line as jar it doesn't print anything.

org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream@214c265e

readLine() gives null during command line run.

Could anyone please help !

Comment: I found it a bit hard to follow what you’re trying to do, but it sounds like it should work. Perhaps you can share a small sample project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Basically from a parent jar file class, I am trying to read a property file inside a dependency jar's classpath. I will create a sample project to share

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, It's work for me.

Create this class at the app project

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("yourpackage")
public class AppConfig {
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("common.properties")
    static class default{}
}
```

If you want to read a config file by different profiles (-Dspring.profiles.active)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("yourpackage")
public class AppConfig {
    @Profile("alpha")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("common-alpha.properties")
    static class Alpha{}

    @Profile("staging")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("common-staging.properties")
    static class Staging{}

    @Profile("production")
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("common-production.properties")
    static class Production{}
}
```

You can use spring @Autowired annotation as below, but make sure you annotate your class with @Component or similar ones.

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

You can get the property in your properties file

```
 env.getProperty("property")
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: I can give a try but I want the property source to be a argument parameter, not a hardcoded static file

Comment: @PropertySource("${propertiesArgument}.properties") and you just pass -DpropertiesArgument on command line parameter supplied during application launch.